# Swift: Conditional casts not needed but "must"?

Tags: swift, casting

I get a warning for "as? AnyObject" that "conditional casts always succeeds". So "?" it is not needed!?
If I remove the "?", I get an error, that I must have "optional" :

```
func toDictionary() -> [String: AnyObject] {
    var retval = [String: AnyObject]()
    if let
        steeringItems   = self.steeringItems   as? AnyObject,
        destinationPath = self.destinationPath as? AnyObject
    {
        retval["steeringItems"] = steeringItems
        retval["gDstPath"] = destinationPath
    }
    return retval
}
```

What is the correct way?

Comment: What's the type of `steeringItems` and `destinationPath`? Sounds like you just want to assign them directly to the dictionary without any optional binding – as they're not optionals, and can be freely upcasted to `AnyObject`.

Comment: I think the issue is that you are casting to AnyObject, which it already knows, but you should be casting to the expected type of those properties such as String/Int

Comment: `AnyObject` does what it says. It's _any object_. Casting to `AnyObject` when you don't need to is like casting `Fruit` to `Anything`. Fruit is a thing, so the cast will always succeed.

Comment: Using the correct datatype like String for "destinationPath" doesn't change anything. It will generate an error telling "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not String".

Comment: As @originaluser2 is asking, how are you declaring the `steeringItems` and `destinationPath` properties?

Comment: Re your last comment: now that you get an accurate error message, we see that `self.steeringItems` and `self.destinationPath` are not Optionals, so you can't use `if let` in this case.

Comment: @Laffen: path is String and steeringItems is var steeringItems : [SteeringItem] = []  where class SteeringItem : NSObject, NSCoding {...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optional binding is used to in order to unwrap optionals, and your `steeringItems` and `destinationPath` are non-optionals.

Also, because `destinationPath` is a `String`, which can be freely bridged to `NSString` and  `steeringItems` is a `[SteeringItem]`, which can be bridged to `NSArray` (as `SteeringItem` is an `NSObject`) – you can freely up-cast them to `AnyObject`. Therefore you don't need to do any conditional casting (as it would never fail).

So just don't use optional binding! Just assign the properties directly:

```
func toDictionary() -> [String:AnyObject] {

    var retval = [String: AnyObject]()

    retval["steeringItems"] = steeringItems
    retval["gDstPath"] = destinationPath

    return retval
}
```

Or more concisely:

```
func toDictionary() -> [String:AnyObject] {
    return ["steeringItems":steeringItems, "gDstPath":destinationPath]
}
```